# Automatic Execution in response to cell value change

Tags: vba, excel, automation, execution

I know the code probably isn't very good but I'm still learning VBA.

I've created a worksheet that organizes my college course list but I'm trying to make it so that the code executes automatically when I change a value in the first two columns.

An "x" in the first column selects that as a completed course which subtracts the credit hours for that class from the total hours required. An "S" and some number in the second column denotes a semester and sums up the credit hours to be taken per semester, for example, if I enter "S1" next to "Study and Careers in Engineering", then it will take that 1 credit hour for that class and add it to the total amount of hours for the entire semester.

The two codes are completely independent of each other.

Screenshot of worksheet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTsiy.png

Code:

```
Private Sub Calculations()

    Dim creditsLeft As Integer creditsLeft = 130

    For i = 3 To 43
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "x" Then creditsLeft = (creditsLeft - Cells(i, 8)) Next i

    Range("J3").Value = creditsLeft


    Dim S1creds, S2creds, S3creds, S4creds, S5creds, S6creds As Integer

    For i = 3 To 43
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S1" Then S1creds = (S1creds + Cells(i, 8))
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S2" Then S2creds = (S2creds + Cells(i, 8))
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S3" Then S3creds = (S3creds + Cells(i, 8))
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S4" Then S4creds = (S4creds + Cells(i, 8))
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S5" Then S5creds = (S5creds + Cells(i, 8))
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S6" Then S6creds = (S6creds + Cells(i, 8)) 
    Next i

    Range("J9").Value = "Sem 1 Hrs: " 
    Range("J10").Value = "Sem 2 Hrs: "
    Range("J11").Value = "Sem 3 Hrs: " 
    Range("J12").Value = "Sem 4 Hrs: "
    Range("J13").Value = "Sem 5 Hrs: " 
    Range("J14").Value = "Sem 6 Hrs: "

    Range("K9").Value = S1creds 
    Range("K10").Value = S2creds
    Range("K11").Value = S3creds 
    Range("K12").Value = S4creds
    Range("K13").Value = S5creds 
    Range("K14").Value = S6creds

    End Sub
```

Comment: see the `Worksheet_Change` event. That will help you accomplish what you are after. If you get stuck, reply back with where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need VBA for that.

I3: `=130-SUMIF(A3:A43,"x",H3:H43)`
K9: `=SUMIF(B3:B43,"S1",H3:H43)`
K10: `=SUMIF(B3:B43,"S2",H3:H43)`
K11: `=SUMIF(B3:B43,"S3",H3:H43)`
K12: `=SUMIF(B3:B43,"S4",H3:H43)`
K13: `=SUMIF(B3:B43,"S5",H3:H43)`
K14: `=SUMIF(B3:B43,"S6",H3:H43)`